# /bin/ksh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, ksh, shebang, source-command

I have script with `#!/bin/ksh` in the first line.
When I try to execute this script (run `./myscript.sh`) the error occurred:

```
-bash: ./myscript.sh: /bin/ksh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

But when I execute this script through `source myscript.sh` or `bash myscript.sh` command - script runs successfully.

Yes, ksh is not installed and it is correct to install this.
But I can't understand different behavior `./` and `bash` or `source`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- When a script is executed with `./` the interpreter from the shebang line is invoked.
- with `source` the current shell is used (`source` is a bash extension, so you have to be running bash)
- with `bash script.sh` the bash shell in your PATH is invoked with the shellscript.